# Django -- Pre-populating Hidden Fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my user signup process the user first creates their account, then creates a LIST object, and then is directed to the dashboard of the LIST object they just created. To achieve this I need to be able to access the list_id of the recently created LIST object so I can pass it into the next view/template. list_id is the primary key for the LIST table/class and as such I don't want a user to create a value for this -- it auto-increments. Here is the field from the model:

```
class List(models.Model):
    list_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Description of list_id from MySQL:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| list_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

Here is the view:

```
@login_required
@permission_required('social_followup.add_list')
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        list_form = forms.ListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            list_create = list_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'List {0} created'.format(list_create.list_id))
            up, _ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, list_id=list_create)
            return redirect(reverse('user_dashboard', args=(2,)))  # 2 is just an example
    else:
        list_form = forms.ListForm()

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'dashboard/create.html', {'list_form': list_form, })
```

However, I've found that when I don't include list_id as part of the form, I am not able to access that attribite (doing list_create.list_id returns `None` when list_id is not a field). In my template I have the list_id field hidden like this:

```
<div class="control-group {% if list_form.list_id.errors %}error{% endif %}">
    <div class="controls">
        {{ list_form.list_id.as_hidden }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Since list_id is required and hidden, the form won't validate because list_id has no value. However, if I remove list_id as a field, I cannot seem to access the list_id attribute in my view. Is there a way to auto populate this field with whatever the next list_id should be so that I can grab the value with list_create.list_id, and keep the field hidden? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need `list_id` in your form, assuming I'm following correctly when your lists are actually created.  Can you add the relevant parts of your model definition (at least the list_id field definition and whatever actually creates it, probably the save method) to the question?

Comment: I updated the question with the model field and the description of the field from MySQL.

Comment: If `ListForm` is a model form for that model, and you haven't done anything odd with its save method, `list_id` should be available in your view as soon as you save.  It'll autopopulate when the object gets written to the database.

Comment: When I try to access that attribute though, through `list_create.list_id` after the save method, if there was no `list_id` field than something like `print list_create.list_id` evaluates to `None` rather than something like `24`. Am I trying to access the list_id attribute incorrectly then?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case after saving the form, not with a field declared as your primary key.  Assuming there's not a commit=false sneaking in somewhere or something else that would change the save behavior.

Comment: Actually, one long shot I would try is renaming the field.  Django creates fields to handle foreign keys by appending `_id` to the name of the declared foreign key field, and it's possible that something's getting thrown off because `list_id` looks like such a field.

Comment: Sadly I can't change the name of the field because it's a legacy DB that is already in production and would require going through a fairly large python code base to change all instances of `list_id`. So it seems like I cannot access `list_create.list_id` without the `list_id` field because then it's not actually part of the `forms.ListForm`, which makes sense. However after `save()` a new instance has been created. Can I grab the `list_id` from the new instance of that object after save without `list_create.list_id` and if so how? Thanks for the help, btw

Comment: You could work around the db issue by declaring the `db_column` attribute on your field, but that wouldn't help with the python code base.  Maybe try accessing it using the `pk` alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys do not exist before `.save()` has been called. If you want to access the PK later after the form has been saved, you can access it by passing to your template

`list_form = forms.ListForm(instance=list_create)`

And then in your template

`{{list_form.instance.id}}`